# how to trigger spellcheck when press on space tinymce - js

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I need to implement spell checker when pressing on space in tinymce. How can I implement this? which is the event need to trigger this action?

```
                  editor.on('KeyUp', function (e) {
                     if (e.keyCode == 32){
                        //need to trigger spellchecker
                     }
                  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you `init` your TinyMCE instance, you could setup the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var spellcheckTimeout;
    
    function triggerSpellcheck() {
        clearTimeout(spellcheckTimeout);
        spellcheckTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceSpellCheck');
        }, 1000);
    }

    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        plugins: [
            "spellchecker"
        ],
        toolbar: "spellchecker",
        setup : function(editor) {
            editor.on("keyup", function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 32) {
                    console.log('test');
                    triggerSpellcheck();
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

See this [TinyMCE Fiddle](https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/Muhaab) for a working example.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its worked for me. one doubt.. why we use clearTimeout() here?

Comment: how can it be possible to find the spell checker is enabled or not?